# Confused by the documentation of chrome.app.isInstalled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to understand how to check on my web page if the user has my packaged chrome app installed already. If they don't I'll let them install it. If they do, I'll take them over to the app using the new url_handlers magic. The documentation here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest
says that I can check `chrome.app.isInstalled` "from a page contained within your app's URLs"

That links to here https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest which says that "urls" is an attribute of the "app" in the manifest. However, if I add that attribute to my manifest, that changes my app from a packaged app into a hosted app, according to the error message I get when I try to test it from the extensions page.

So…. how do I test if my packaged chrome app (a .crx the user gets from the store) is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That method is only for legacy packaged apps, which are deprecated.

Comment: The chrome store itself knows. Seems unfair that it can tell whether apps are installed, but apps cannot! Anyway, thanks. Is it worth doing a feature request, or is there a reason they don't want pages to be able to be user friendly?

Comment: Yes, you should file a bug. It's possible that it is just an oversight. http://crbug.com/new

Comment: I found this existing feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227178